# How to fetch the code of the binary installed on a  machine?

Tags: source-code

I am a newbie in linux and using ubuntu as my desktop os. Most of the time I feel the need to look at the code of the utility like ls, rm etc. Can anyone tell me how to get the code for these utilities.

Currently I am looking for the implementation of ssh-copy-id utility.

Answer (score 4):

You can fetch the source of a package with:

```
apt-get source [package]
```

Make sure you have the deb-src lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` generally, copying the `deb` lines and changing `deb` to `deb-src` is enough.

If you don't know the name of the package with the file in question, you can get that info with apt-file. However, I can't remember how off the top of my head. I recommend reading the docs. :)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. But I have one doubt, I want to retrieve the code of ssh-copy-id, the command exists but apt-get source ssh-copy-id fails to find the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ssh-copy-id is the name of the command, not the name of the package.I have updated my answer.

Comment: ssh-copy-id is shell script. It is it's source code :)

Answer (score 0):

First use **dpkg -S** to find what package the binary belongs to e.g:

```
dpkg -S /bin/ls
```

this will output a line like

> coreutils: /bin/ls

This means that coreutils is the package that /bin/ls belongs to. Now use apt-get to fetch source of that package

```
sudo apt-get source coreutils
```